# How to Get the Postion of Elements in the Gallery when the User Scrolling it?

Tags: android, gallery

Hai All,
         I have a Gallery which Contains text Value such as Movie, Music, Games, Magzine etc., My Problem is, Whenever the User Scrolls the Gallery, I want to get the Postion of the Element.

For Instance,
              User Scrolls the Gallery from Movie to Games means then i have to get the Position of Currently Selected Element ie postion of Games.

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: please check my blog post on the Gallery control
http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-gallery-control.html it may help you

Answer (score 0):

in your Oncreate do somthing like this.....

```
{
 gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos ,long arg3) {

               //you will have the selected position in variable pos   
                }

}
```

hope it will work